# Error using countifs function in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft

I'm trying to use the `countifs` function to count occurrences of text within a multi-column range when another piece of text appears in a different range.

In the table below, A1:A12 is named colors and b1:e12 is named objects.  In this example, the ranges are side by side, but in my actual situation they are separated by many other columns.

My goal would be to count the number of times that the text "airplane" appears with the color "red."

The formula I'm trying to use is

```
=countifs(colors,"red",objects,"airplane")
```

but it doesn't work whether I enter it as a simple formula or as an array or if I actually enter the data ranges like this:

```
=countifs(a1:a12, "red", b1:312, "airplane")
```

[image: table example]

Answer (score 1):

As already stated `COUNTIFS()` function only work with ranges for the **[criteria_ranges]** and with each ranges must have same number of rows and columns.

That said the following issue can be resolved using with `SUM()` those using Modern Excel or with `SUMPRODUCT()` function --> multiples the arrays/ranges together to return the sum of the products.

Older versions can also use `SUM()` but that would need a extra keying while exiting the edit mode, that is need to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C15</kbd>

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A15=A2:A13)*(B15=B2:E13))
```

---

**Note:** Please ensure to adjust cell reference and ranges accordingly as per your suit.

---

Answer (score 0):

From Excel Help for countifs(): "Each additional range must have the same number of rows and columns as the criteria_range1 argument. The ranges do not have to be adjacent to each other."

Your second range isn't the same size as your first range.

Comment: Yes.  I know the ranges are different sizes and I was thinking that might be the problem.  What can I use instead?

Comment: Presumably making the smaller range the same size as the larger range will work if you leave the extra cells empty. If the extra cells make you sheet look weird, you might be able to hide the extra columns.